# how to get the email-id of the receiver who clicks the url in the html page sent to him via e-mail from the radio button data source option

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, radio-button, query-string

I have a mailer in which i have to fill the credentials in the textbox except for the recipients to whom i am sending the mail.For choosing the recipients, i have used radio buttons to select the recipients from database or an excel sheet or a text file.

```
 SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mystring"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getFiles();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var list = getFiles();
                dd1.DataSource = list;
                dd1.DataTextField = "Key";
                dd1.DataValueField = "Value";
                dd1.DataBind();
            }
        }  
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                SendHTMLMail();

            }




            void SendHTMLMail()
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
                string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string output = regx.ToString();    
                string count = 0.ToString();
                output = readFile;
                string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);
                output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
                {
                    var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
                    return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&count={count}";
                }));


                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();  

                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);


                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;      
                Msg.Body = output.ToString();
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                if (fuAttachment.HasFile)          
                {
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);

                    Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));    
                }
                if (RadioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    sql.Open();
                    string s = "select * from address";
                    SqlCommand t = new SqlCommand(s, sql);
                    t.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sql.Close();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM address1";
                    cmd.Connection = sql;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sql.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    sql.Close();

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {

                        Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
                    }              
                }
                else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    string connectionString = "";
                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName); 
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);   

                        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                        {

                            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }    
                        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd; 
                           dAdapter.Fill(dt);  
                        con.Close();


                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {

                            Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
                        }    
                    }
                }
                else if (RadioButton3.Checked)
                {
                    if (FileUpload2.HasFile) 
                    {


                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);

                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                        FileUpload2.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
                        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        string[] toAddressArray;
                        toAddressArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                        foreach (string a in toAddressArray)
                        {
                            Msg.To.Add(a);

                        }
                    }
                }

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(Msg);   
                    Msg = null;
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
                }   
            }

        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getFiles()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/App_Data"));
            var fi = di.EnumerateFiles("*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            var files = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();      
            foreach (FileInfo file in fi)
            {
                files.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, file.FullName));
            }
            return files;
        }
```

Now, what i want is to get the email id of the recipient who clicks the link in the html page that i have sent to him as the mail body. How to get the email id which is among one of the three radio button data sources?Also, i want to get the current date and time at which he clicks the link . I want to pass that email id and current date and time in this query string-

```
 return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&count={count}";
```

Comment: Have you ever see an application automatically getting the user email address without asking to provide?There is no way to magically get an email address of a client its a security issue,they have to or you have to ask them to enter their email addresses

Comment: i have done the same thing with textbox and it worked. when i entered the recipient in textbox, then i got his mail id when he clicked it like this - Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);                                                                                          i just want to get the id when i am using these radio buttons @TAHASULTANTEMURI

Comment: so you just want to get the id of checkbox clicked?

Comment: what i am doing is on checking the radio button, i am choosing the data source from which i will fetch the recipients list. There are 3 radio boxes- one for database, one for excel; sheet, one for text file. now the recipient would be from among these three options. So i just want to get his mail id on click of the url which would be from any of these three options. I want the code for getting the recipient from these three option and pass it to the query string.  @TAHASULTANTEMURI   i dont want the id but the recipient which is among the rows of the data source

Comment: provide the solution now @TAHASULTANTEMURI

Comment: The code seems to be correct, at least for the part where you get the different kind of email addresses from different datasources. If you have problem in this code I think that the only solution is using the debugger. Place a breakpoint inside the SendHTMLMail method and run your program until it hits the breakpoint. At that point follow your code line by line with F10 and look at the value of the variables while they are set. In particular what will be added to Msg.To list.

Comment: everything is working fine in this code as i didn't write any code to get the mail id if the recipient. What i want is when the recipient receives my mail and clicks on the link in the html page, i want to get the email- id of that recipient. I don't know how to do this. I want the email id of the person who clicks the link. Also, that person's email id is one of the records from database, excel worksheet or text file. i don"t know how to fetch this @Steve

Comment: So you want to send an HTML page with an internal link to your recipients identifying the recipient, but it seems that you have more than one recipient and each recipient requires a personalized link to be identifieable. So I don't think that you can add the same HTML to all your recipients and send out a single mail. You need separate mails with different links for each recipients.

Comment: is it possible that i retrieve all the recipients together from the data source say database or excel and then auto send mail one by one so that in this way i can get the mail id?

Comment: is there away in which we can compare the mail id of the person who clicks the link with the records in database and return it if it exists @Steve

Comment: Usually this is done using an code generated by Guid.NewGuid.ToString("N") and adding this code to the link clicked by your recipients. But of course you should store this code in a database table together with your email address. When the user clicks the link extract the code and search the database for your email

Comment: As explained you need to create a separate HTML with the personalized link and add just one email address to the Msg.To list and then send the email. I think you need to rework a little your sendHTMLMail introducing some kind of loop around your logic

Comment: can you provide me the code? @Steve

Comment: Sorry this is too big task to do in my available time

Comment: its okay! i understand.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you help me in this-   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941738/how-to-get-the-url-and-the-product-code-contained-in-it-separately