# how to update and read the value of sql column on click of the same button

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-update, reader

what i am doing is on click of a button, i am updating a sql column by adding +1 to it. I faced no problem doing that. Now what i want is that for the same button click event, i want to read the value of that column which i have updated and send it in a query string to another page. here is the code-

```
int i=0;
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sql.Open();
    string r = "update counter set m_id=m_id+1 where id=1";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(r, sql);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Close();
    {
        SendHTMLMail();
    }





void SendHTMLMail()
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
    string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string output = regx.ToString();    
    string count = 0.ToString();
    output = readFile;
    string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);

    //here i want to read the value of m_id that i have updated as shown above and setting it to 'i' and passing this i  to the query string//

    sql.Open();
    string re = "select m_id from counter where id=1";
    SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand(re, sql);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader read = ccmd.ExecuteReader();
    {
       while (read.Read())
          i =int.Parse(read["m_id"].ToString());

    }
    sql.Close();

    output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
    {   
      var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
      return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&count={count}&mailer_id={i}";
    }));
```

now, the problem is instead of getting updated say from 5 to 6, m_id is getting updated to 7

Comment: Your real problem is when two people click this button at the same time and get the same number

Comment: Somethig is not quite right in the code posted. In the SendHtmlMail you declare a command named _ccmd_ but then you execute a command named _com_ This second command doesn't exist in this method and, unless it is a global variable, you should get a compile time error. Please, to avoid closure for a missing [MCVE] post the exact code that creates the problem

Comment: i just want to execute two sql commands on submit of button. Is it possible? At first i want to update a column by adding +1 to it. Secondly, i want to read the value of the column i have updated in first command. So is it possible if yes then how? @Steve

Comment: Yes it is possible, albeit you can do everything with just one call and one command. But please, explain. Is SendHTMLMail method nested inside the btnSubmit_Click? If yes, could you fix the code shown above adding the appropriate closing curly brace? As is it is unclear if the two methods are separate

Comment: yes its a method which is doing stuff. You just take the scenario where you have one button and on clicking it, at first you want to increment a column by +1 and secondly you want to read the updated value of that column and assign it to a variable. @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *batch* commands together and execute just one command instead of calling two times to the database

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sql.Open();
    string r = @"update counter set m_id=m_id+1 where id=1;
                 select m_id from counter where id=1;";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(r, sql);
    int result = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
    sql.Close();
    {
        SendHTMLMail(result);
    }
}
```

At this point the SendHTMLMail method (nested or not) can receive the *result* variable and avoid any call to the database engine. Note that in this case I have changed the ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteScalar to get back the only value returned by the select.

However, if want still keep the things separated, then you need to change the code inside your SendHTMLMail to something like this

```
// just change the CommandText to avoid reexecuting the INSERT
com.CommandText = "select m_id from counter where id=1";

// No more needed
// SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand(re, sql);

// Get the reader from the SqlCommand
SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();
{
    .... go on with reading
```

Comment: yeah i am new to this platform so didn't know. I have accepted. Done!

Comment: I have told you about this because I see seven question without accepts. At the end is up to you to decide which of these questions had received useful answers

Comment: can you help me with one more problem? @Steve

Comment: @manusharma It is better if you post a new question. So many more people can see it and help you. Of course you are free to post the link to the new question here as a comment so I will be notified immediately

Comment: I seriously need help in this as i'm stuck. It would be of great help if u have a look at this. Here's the link-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906060/how-to-get-the-email-id-of-the-receiver-who-clicks-the-url-in-the-html-page-sent?noredirect=1#comment90762740_51906060

Comment: can you please help?