# how to get the url and the product code contained in it separately

Tags: c#, .net, regex, smtp, query-string

I have a mailer in which i am sending a html page as the mail body. The html page has some links. What i am doing here is identifying those links and replacing those links with a link to my page and sending the link as a parameter in query string along with a parameter 'username' which i enter in a textbox. Here is the code-

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/one.html"));
                string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string output = regx.ToString();    
                 output = readFile;
                string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);

                output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
                  {   
                var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
                  return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}";
                 }));
```

There is a product code in that url. What i want is the product code along with the link. The link can be- http://example.in/next/pr-01.html
pr-01 is the product code. The product code is in this format- pr-01,pr-02....
I am new to .net and haven't used regex earlier so i have no idea how to get the product code and complete link separately and pass them in query string as shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"pr-.*([\d])");
```

Comment: how to return the product code? Also, the product code is the part of link(regx)

Comment: `string str = "http://example.in/next/pr-0134534.html";
            Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"pr-.*([\d])");
            Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(str);

            string fileName = myMatch.Groups[0].Value;`
In FileName you wil get your product code.

Comment: In the url variable you want only product code or full link value?

Comment: i want both but separetely and in url , i am already getting the whole link

Comment: `output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
            {
                var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
                Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"pr-.*([\d])");
                Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(url);

                string fileName = myMatch.Groups[0].Value;
                return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&productCode={fileName}";
            }));`

Please check this code

Comment: and what if in the case where the product code be anything like- abc01 or trk-54 or product-abc? Then how can we get it? The only info we have is that the product code would be after last \ in the link and before a . like- xyz/shop/health/product-abc1.html? What would be the regular expression pattern in that case in place of this- @"pr-.*([\d])"

Comment: then you could also use LastIndexOf() method of string and get the substring out of it excluding ".html" part.
Or you want to only work with regex for this also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178439/discussion-between-dhiren-and-manu-sharma).

Comment: Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"[^\/]?.*\/(.*)?.*\/(.*)\/(.*)?.*\.");
                Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(Uri.UnescapeDataString(url));

                string fileName = myMatch.Groups[3].Value;
Try this regex and check

Comment: can you help me in this as well-   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960236/how-to-get-the-email-id-of-the-recipient-on-click-of-a-link-and-send-that-mail-i#

Answer (score 0):

Although using a regular expression is an option, it can also be done without *(which might even be better for performance)*.
Here below the last segment is taken from the url (`pr-01.html`),
followed by taking only the part of it before the file extension (`.html`) starting with a `.`,
which is the productcode `pr-01`.

```
String url = "http://example.in/next/pr-01.html";
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
String fileName = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1]; // pr-01.html
String productCode = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf(".")); // pr-01
```

**EDIT**

The above parsing routine can be combined with your code as shown here below.
The last line shows how to include the productcode in the querystring *(you might have to use an other querystring parameter name)*.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/one.html"));
string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string output = regx.ToString();    
output = readFile;
string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);

output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
{  
    Uri uri = new Uri(match.Value, UriKind.Absolute);
    String fileName = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1]; // pr-01.html
    String productCode = Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("."))); // pr-01

    var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
    return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&productcode={productCode}"; // << Include the productcode in the querystring.
}));
```

Comment: i have to use regular expression as i don't know that on which link in the html page , the user gonna click.  "http://example.in/next/pr-01.html" - it is just an example. I want the solution using regex

Comment: what i want is- in the link there is a product code i.e the link contains the product code. So i want to get both the link and the subpart(product code). After this i will replace the link with my link and send the link name and product name as parameters to query string

Comment: Can you check whether this code can deal with some other url's you have? As long as the last part matches the pattern: `productcode` + `.` it will be parsed; the part in front of the productcode doesn't matter.

Comment: can you provide the solution using the approach i have used as above?(using regex)

Comment: How do you want to use the productcode in the url `http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}`? Does it have to be appended as a separate querystring argument?

Comment: yes i want to send- 1. the complete link   2. the product code   in the query string separately. The query string would be-return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&productcode={pc}";

Comment: it is throwing an error- : 'Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length'

Comment: Please check what the value is in `match.Value`. From your question, I understand that it must be an url according to the regex already present.

Comment: it is matching the regex regx pattern.  provide the solution in terms of regex instead of uri

Comment: I don't understand. What is the value in `match.Value` on which it fails? My answer only takes care of stripping the productcode, not the whole `html`file parsing.

Comment: my streamreader is mapping the one.html page from appdata which is the html page that i am sending as mail body. In that html page there are several links. What i am getting is, on clicking the link i am replacing it with my link and sending some parameters in query string. In query string, i am retrieving the link on clicking it. Now what i want is the product code which is a subpart of the link and want to send it as a separate parameter in query string